# File Dialog ask save as file

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

I'm trying to use the following in my GUI

```
def SaveFile():
sf = filedialog.asksaveasfile(defaultextension=".txt",
                              mode='w',
                              filetypes=[
                                ("Text file", ".txt"),
                                ("HTML file", ".html"),
                                ("All files", ".*"),
                                ])

sf=u'\u003c'
sf.encode('utf8')
if sf is None:
    return
sf.write('\n'.join(listbox2.get(0,END)))
sf.close()
```

I get this error:

```
 sf.write ('\n'.join(listbox2.get(0,END)))
 ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

If I use this its works fine, BUT I can't use a custom name for the said file.

```
with open("Name.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(listbox2.get(0, END)))
```

Any Idea what I'm not doing right? I've searched here and asked on other forums with no answers.

Comment: You first define `sf` as the result of `asksaveasfile` and then one line later you redefine it to be a string. Like the error says, a string does not have a `write` method.

Answer (score 1):

`filedialog.asksaveasfile()` produces a `TextIOWrapper` which contains a property `name`. You can use `sf.name` instead of `"Name.txt"`.

You could also use:

```py
with sf:
    sf.write(...)
```

or

```py
sf.write(...)
sf.close()
```

as you attempted.

Or at least you could if you didn't overwrite sf with `sf=u'\u003c'`.

Comment: If I don't use the `sf=u'\u003c'` I get this error:

    `An error occurred: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 738219-738235: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @spike666spike666, this seems to be caused by `sf.encode('utf8')` which doesn't seem necessary either.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Bryan Oakley and Minty. I changed `asksaveasfile` to `asksaveasfilename`. Here is my now working function.

```
def SaveFile():    
try:
    file1=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=
                                [("text file", "*.txt"),
                                 ("HTML file", ".html"),
                                 ("All files", ".*")],
                                  defaultextension=".txt")
    sf=open(file1, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    sf.write("\n".join(listbox2.get(0, END)))
    if sf is not None:
        return
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
    sf.close()
```